# IFRAME javascript close()?

Tags: jquery

I can't seem to get self.close() to work on iframes. I know they aren't popups so it's quite normal that they don't but is there a work around?

Comment: What behavior would you want it to have on `.close()`? And why did you tag it with [tag:php]? o.O

Comment: Does this help http://jsfiddle.net/8CQJG/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

closing an iFrame is something the parent should do. Eg by just removeing it as [Frank Astin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/886499/frank-astin) demonstraes in his [link](http://jsfiddle.net/8CQJG).

Comment: I've made three functions: one to grab the document element of our iFrame, one to change the text of the button (to prove it works), and one to override the onclick event of the button.

Comment: Now i got the Solution of your helps guys
The iframe source code :
Code:
<html>
<body>

<p>Clicking close will close this window.</p>
<input type="button" onclick="self.close()" value="Close Window"/>

</body>
</html>